# xfreerdp disable own decoration

Tags: linux-mint, mate

I need disable decoration window xfreerdp(started via keys):
xfreerdp /v:192.168.132.11 /t:NAME-window +compression +clipboard -themes -wallpaper -bitmap-cache -offscreen-cache /kbd:0x419 /size:1920x1020 /bpp:16 /u:MYDOM\myuser
[example problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcvZ2.png)
HOW TO fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:
Need install **freerdp2-x11**, and start with -decoration**s** instead -decoration

xfreerdp /v:192.168.132.11 /t:NAME-window +compression +clipboard ***-decorations*** -themes -wallpaper -bitmap-cache -offscreen-cache /kbd:0x419 /workarea /bpp:16 /u:MYDOM\myuser /drive:share,/home/myuser/share

Solved.